# spark connects on port 8020 instead of 9000 and get connection refused

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have installed `hadoop3.2.1` and  `Spark3.1.1`. I tried to read hdfs file data from Spark but i got the following error:

`Call From vm/ip1 to vm:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

Note that `core-site.xml` is configured as follows: `<property> <name>fs.default.name</name> <value>hdfs://vm:9000/</value> </property>`

So, how can i proceed ?

Comment: Where is your xml file located? Spark is running in the VM? What master mode are you using?

Comment: xml file in /etc/hadoop directory , spark is running in the VM that is selected as master , and I do not specify the master mode? do you mean the spark master mode ?

Comment: Master like local, or yarn, yes. Your XML file needs to be copied (or symlinked) into `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and make sure `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable is set to `/etc/hadoop`. If everything is running in the same machine, you don't really need HDFS nor would you need to set up the hostname in the xml file